# Fastest way to read files in a multi-processing environment? C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, caching, ravendb

I have the following challenge:

I have a Azure Cloud Worker Role with many instances.  Every minute, each instance spins up about 20-30 threads.  In each thread, it needs to read some metadata about how to process the thread from 3 objects.  The objects/data reside in a remote RavenDb and even though RavenDb is very fast at retrieving the objects via HTTP, it is still under a considerable load from 30+ workers that are hitting it 3 times per thread per minute (about 45 requests/sec).  Most of the time (like 99.999%) the data in RavenDb does not change.

I've decided to implement local storage caching. First, I read a tiny record which indicates if the metadata has changed (it changes VERY rarely), and then I read from local file storage instead of RavenDb, if local storage has the object cached.  I'm using File.ReadAllText()

This approach appears to be bogging the machine down and procesing slows down considerably.  I'm guessing the disks on "Small" Worker Roles are not fast enough.

Is there anyway, I can have OS help me out and cache those files? Perhaps there is an alternative to caching of this data?

I'm looking at about ~1000 files of varying sizes ranging from 100k to 10mb in size stored on each Cloud Role instance

Comment: Perhaps using a `StreamReader` and Streams to read lines instead of putting all 10MBs of text per worker in memory? Can't wait to see an accepted solution on this!

Comment: Thanks.. but I need to convert "lines" into a JSON strings that I need to then convert to C# objects.  Not sure if StreamReader is going to solve this, if I need the file in full

Comment: Ah probably not then if you can't parse line by line  =/

Comment: Why not cache in memory? File IO will always be slower if not memory mapped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a straight answer, but three possible options:

**Use the built-in RavenDB caching mechanism**

My initial guess is that your caching mechanism is actually hurting performance. The RavenDB client has caching built-in (see here for how to fine-tune it: https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/client-api/how-to/setup-aggressive-caching)

The problem you have is that the cache is local to each server. If server A downloaded a file before, server B will still have to fetch it if it happens to process that file the next time.

One possible option you could implement is divide the workload. For example:

- Server A => fetch files that start with A-D
- Server B => fetch files that start with E-H
- Server C => ...

This would ensure that you optimize the cache on each server.

**Get a bigger machine**

If you still want to employ your own caching mechanism, there are two things that I imagine could be the bottleneck:

- Disk access
- Deserialization of the JSON

For these issues, the only thing I can imagine would be to get bigger resources:

- If it's the disk, use premium storage with SSD's.
- If it's deserialization, get VM's with a bigger CPU

**Cache files in RAM**

Alternatively, instead of writing the files to disk, store them in memory and get a VM with more RAM. You shouldn't need THAT much RAM, since 1000 files * 10MB is still just 1 GB. Doing this would eliminate disk access and deserialization.

But ultimately, it's probably best to first measure where the bottleneck is and see if it can be mitigated by using RavenDB's built-in caching mechanism.

Comment: This is VERY interesting!  How do I make the client subscribe to the changes and invalidate cache for the changed objects automatically?  I've seen examples on Ravendb site that indicate that I can subscribe to changes, but not showing how to make the agressive cache invalidate itself

Comment: You shouldn't need to subscribe to any changes or invalidate the cache. When you make a request, the RavenDB server will answer with a 304 - Not Modified status code and the RavenDB client should then give you back the cached version. As soon as a document changes, RavenDB will return a 200 again.

Comment: for agressive caching as well?

Comment: According to the docs, the server will send a notification when a document changes: `The way it works is that the client subscribes to server notifications and by taking advantage of them is able to invalidate cached documents when they are changed` There's a small chance you get a stale document because there's a time between updating the document and sending the notification. So, at least in theory, just enabling aggresive caching should do the job. At the bottom of that documentation page, it mentions a few tweaks you can use